# Handling exceptions for extern declared object initialization

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, extern, throw

Suppose I have code

```
// state.h
extern struct AppState {
  AppState() {
    throw std::runtime_error("The runtime error");
  }
} appState; 

// state.cpp
#include "state.h"
AppState appState = AppState();
```

How do I catch exception thrown during construction of `appState`?

Since there's a way to throw exceptions in such situations, I suppose there is a way to catch them.

Comment: _"How do I catch exception thrown during construction of appState?"_ Embed the constructor calls into a `try ... catch ...` block?? I don't understand your question, or what should be specific for constructor calls vs. other function calls? Probably the `AppState appState = AppState();` statement needs to be handled within a try catch

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to have access to the instance of `AppState` by including `#include "state.h"` anywhere in my code, that's the reason for it to be globally initialized. However, some initialization code might throw exceptions and I have no idea how to catch them for a globally initialized object.

Comment: Rather give `AppState` an appropriate _Factory_ and / or `Singleton` class.

Comment: So there's no way of indicating a failing initialization due to `throw`, of a globally initialized object?

Comment: No, it will go straight away to the unhandled exception handler (`atexit()`).

Comment: @Ri0ee - What are you going to do in a potential catch handler? You *need* an AppState and you cannot get one, because the error was totally catastrophic. Then what?! Give up is a reasonable option.  :-)  Otherwise, the next thing you try might just throw as well.

Comment: Considering that there are nested components inside appState, indication as to which on of them failed would be useful. Currently the app terminates inevitably, but I won't know the reason. @BoP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's **noway** to catch an exception thrown by a global variable construction. You may received warnings by code linters when declaring them.

If you really need to `catch` the exception, you should warp it by a function, such as:

```cpp
inline AppState& getAppState() {
    static AppState* appState = nullptr;
    if (appState == nullptr) {
        try {
            appState = new AppState{};
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what();
        }
    }
    return *appState;
}
```

Place this utility function at `state.h`, and whenever you want to use the `appState` global, use `getAppState()` instead.

Note: using global variable to store states **might be a bad idea** and may cause some problems including untracked changes and high coupling.